# Neo4j Community edition - how to configure yml to run Docker image via Kitematic CL

Tags: docker, neo4j, yaml, kitematic

I'm new to Docker and I want to fire up a docker Neo4j Community container that I can connect to (port 7474) and that has the Neo4j data and logs stored outside the container in a folder on my desktop. I'm working on a Windows machine.

I'm trying to save a `docker-compose.yml` file and fire it from the Kitematic CL with `docker-compose up -d`

What content should be stored in the yml file? Is there a better/easier way to do this?

```
neo4j:
   image: official/neo4j:latest
   ports:
    - "7474:7474"
volumes:
   - C:/Users/UserME/Desktop/neo4j/
```

Comment: Do you actually need the files on your desktop, or do you just need the data persisted across runs?

Comment: The data needs to persist across runs and does not need to be on the desktop. It can be stored  in another folder (not the default Neo4j one) on the machine but outside the container

Answer (score 0):

Since all you need is the data to be persisted, I'd recommend a named volume:

```
volumes:
    neo4j_data: ~

services:
    neo4j:
        image: neo4j:latest
        volumes:
          - neo4j_data:/data
```